# Opencart Undefined success notification

Tags: notifications, opencart, 2checkout

I am trying to solve a problem which was happened after loading some modules to my opencart server. Everything seems working fine but my site showing "UNDEFINED " in header and I could not find to solve it. Can you tell me where can I find it ?

[Undefined Header in Success notification message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5P6p.jpg)

Comment: Here, You will need to more clarify your question for your issue. Go to admin > System > Tools > Error logs > & then check it. which error get there. It all error mention here in your question. also, are you which opencart version use?

Comment: Dear HarnishDesign
I am using 2.0.3.1 and error log is empty. No error at all. I have even spoken with the developers of the theme. They asked me to reinstal VQMOD but nothing changed. Everything works fine but just showing this undefined is boring me. So if I can evne remove it will be fine instead of showing this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked the screenshot and the problem is in your cart properties. You need to get the error code from error log. Then we can solve the issue.

Comment: Dear @serkanbalta I am still having same issue and still no Error in Error Log; cause it is not an error it is normally a succes

So far I found something I am talking about DIV ID="notification-container", It is returning Header of the notification box undefined but rest working and I can able to add products to my cart.