# Under #shadow-root I saw unwanted Url Links

Tags: shadow-dom, google-developers-console

I was trying to solve a problem in my site about [undefined error in notification area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41037552/opencart-undefined-success-notification) meanwhile in google developers tool I figured out something new to me. While I read documents about ***Shadow-root*** a little and saw many documents telling me  how a wonderful technology is that.Still no clue what is shadow-root :D

But I saw some links under shadow-root style and I though I got hacked somehow please find attached image and please tell me what was about and what can I do .
Thanks in advance.

[shadow-root unwanted links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljug3.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use a kind of blocker extension in your web browser?

This is a CSS rule to exclude / block all the listed sites or trackers.

Comment: I am using Chrome, and yes I have AdBLocker extension installed. Now I feel a little bit conforted but why not all saw it in all webpages ? It confused me at the begining.

Comment: I don't know how AdBlocker is working but I suppose I inject the code only when it detects some specific patterns.